# Animating ng-repeat ng-move in angular 1.2.x

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm having difficulty getting a css animation for movement in an angular `ng-repeat` list.  I have a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KIcTiJ?p=preview

As you can see, the `ng-enter` animation is processed when the plunker is first loaded.  However, I can't find any way to have an animation get triggered for list movement.  In the example, by clicking on the arrows, the ng-hide is processed, and I would expect the ng-move animation to be triggered, but I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding how the ng-repeat move animation is triggered.

In either case, can anyone suggest a better way for me to get angular 1.2 animations applied to this list when I click the left and right arrows in that example?  I have tried alternate methods of generating the ng-repeat (I could use an angular filter instead of an ng-hide), and I've tried different css transitions, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  Any advice here would be greatly appreciated on how to progress.

Sorry if this question seems like a repeat, but I looked through similar questions on stackoverflow, but the only other answers I could find were for the older angular animation framework, or suggested custom javascript animation, which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` animation work if the collection has changed. You can use `$filter` to reflect your change in the collection.

```
<li ng-class="{'text-danger': item == f}" ng-repeat="item in items| filter: filteredData" class="animate-repeat">
  <span>{{item}}</span>
</li>
```

Here `filteredData` is a controller function which execute your filter logic. (you can write custom filter as well)

```
  $scope.filteredData = function(item) {
    return (Math.abs($scope.f - item) < 2);
  }
```

Check the updated <kbd>[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gaY06C?p=preview)</kbd> how animation works.

Comment: Ah ok- by using the $filter instead of ng-hide to modify the displayed items, I am now getting the animations to display: http://plnkr.co/edit/KIcTiJ?p=preview.  Thanks!